How to get the output of the describe() function in a text file in Python?
I have a DataFrame df and I need to export the output of the following command
df['x'].describe()
in an txt file ("output_file.txt") where I am writing on by using
output_file.write("****")
How can I do it ? In R it does exist the sink() function allowing to drive the data to external connection ? Is there a similar way in Python ?

You can store the df['x'].describe() in a variable and then transform it into a string (e.g. with .to_string()). At that point, you can write the variable on the output file.

Is this output just a human readable string or do you need it to be something you can read programatically later?

You could type(df['x'].describe()) to find out what object it is and read its documentation. help(df['x'].describe()) is useful, but has a ton of stuff. dir(df['x'].describe()) will list attributes and methods which may be easier to scan.

In addition to @mozway's approach, you can also use to_csv:
df["x"].describe().to_csv("output_file.txt")

,x
count,100.0
mean,0.4959770065234764
std,0.29531387081900157
min,0.0004173773175585316
25%,0.18038244917910692
50%,0.5087709386952448
75%,0.7310266403961588
max,0.9995205254797668

Or to_markdown:
df["x"].describe().to_markdown("output_file.txt")

|       |            x |
|:------|-------------:|
| count | 100          |
| mean  |   0.473076   |
| std   |   0.300084   |
| min   |   0.00958289 |
| 25%   |   0.221593   |
| 50%   |   0.437081   |
| 75%   |   0.768625   |
| max   |   0.966176   |


That's a good workaround if you need to read again the data

Convert to_string and write it to your file:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.random(100)})

with open('out.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(df['x'].describe().to_string())

Output saved to out.txt:
count    100.000000
mean       0.493497
std        0.311341
min        0.011427
25%        0.214959
50%        0.486842
75%        0.776824
max        0.981829


ok but isn't there a more generci solution with an equivalent of the R's sink() function, for example ? How can I do if I have to export model.summary(), where model is the fit of a linear regression model

I'd say the same with str(model.summary())
